# Custom Authorize Attribute don't get called

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently begun to migrate a ASP.Net MVC **2** project to MVC 4. Now it seems that all worked fine (as far as I can tell for now) except my custom Authorize Attribute, this didn't get called at all.

**Class**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class Authenticated : AuthorizeAttribute
```

**Sample ussage**

```
[Authenticated]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(string password)
```

Has there been any changes? What am I missing?

***Edit***

How would I debug this, when the Attribute methods self didn't get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't any changes in respect to custom action filters. Assuming you have controller/actions decorated with this attribute the `OnAuthorization` will always be called.

Comment: That's what I had thought, but it didn't get called any more. The Attribute itself is defined in another assembly, but that shouldn't matter, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter at all where the attribute is defined.